# converting nsinteger to nsnumber strange number

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber, nsinteger

I have a method that receives an `nsinteger`, then I need to convert it to a `nsnumber`, but I get a really strange number, my code is:

```
+(TarefaMR *)GetTask:(NSInteger *)idTask {   
    NSLog(@"idTask %@",[NSNumber numberWithInteger:idTask]);
    NSInteger *tt=111;    
    NSLog(@"tt %@",[NSNumber numberWithInteger:tt]); 
}
```

my idtask is 888 and I get a 203513664 while the tt variable is working , I get the 111, what can be the problem?

Comment: +(TarefaMR *)GetTask:(NSInteger *)idTask did you mean +(TarefaMR *)GetTask:(NSInteger)idTask

Comment: `NSInteger` is a primitive type, a typedef to `int` or `long long`. It's **not a class.** Why you people don't read the documentation?

Comment: doesnt resolve the problem,keep getting a strange number

Comment: @user2069142 yes, it does if you look carefully what it means. Don't use a pointer to an NSInteger or you will just get the memory address instead of the value

Comment: i removed the * and i keep getting this number : 174447376 instead off 888

Comment: Your doing something else wrong then! How to you call the method?

Comment: i have and object then use : currentTask.noteId=[[allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"noteId"]integerValue]; and i call the method like this [client GetTask:[current noteId]] in didSelectRowAtIndexPath;

Comment: make sure you accept the answers since they are right.

Comment: well, it might be, but i found the problem, it hadnt anything to do with this, sorry for the basic question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `NSInteger` as a reference. Try removing the * from behind every mention to `NSInteger` you do. Remember, `NSInteger` are not objects, they're just a cool way to name "int"s :)